# how to detect available RSS feeds on a web page?

Tags: browser, rss

I'm writing a second edition of  a technical book about a content management system. I am writing a section about how to configure RSS feeds. Then I realized something: It is getting harder to detect RSS in a web browser these days! I wrote about several methods to do this in 2010, and now all the methods I suggested seem to be obsolete.

Firefox seems to have removed their RSS icon. Inded, if this functionality exists in the browser, it seems to be only through a plugin.

As of July 2013 what are the easiest ways to detect an RSS feed if there's no visible sign (an RSS icon, etc).

Are there any websites where you can plug in a URL to see if an RSS feed exists?

**Aha,** I see that in Firefox, you can do **View** --> **Toolbars** --> **Customize** and then choose the icon for Subscribe/Feeds and drag it to your Firefox toolbar. That's one solution... Any others.

**Update #2**. Aha, in IE 10, you can go to **Tools** --> **Feed Discovery** -->(see if a feed exists). If it does, IE will display it and give you some queries and other options for subscribing and filtering.... (On my laptop, the Tools toolbar was hidden. I had to rightclick on the top toolbar, enable **Menu Bar** to make it visible again so I could find the Tools menu.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope you aren't using the term *detect* to describe this in your technical book. Being a programmer myself, I read the title as as "how to programmatically find out what RSS feeds are associated with a web page?", not "how to see visually if there are any RSS/Atom feeds listed in the page header?".

Comment: I no longer see any icon about RSS in View → Toolbars → Customize (Firefox 68.0.2 on Debian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox (at least my Firefox 21), you can go into *Page Info* and *Feeds*. I'm pretty sure this is independent of any add-ons; I got so fed up with having to do that all the time that I hunted down and installed the [RSS Icon In Awesomebar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rss-icon-in-awesombar) add-on. It's a little less un-awesome now. There appears to be a few alternative implementations available.

Comment: Wow, I never never about Page Info. That's a great tip! (Lots of other junk there as well).

Comment: I no longer see anything about Feeds in Page Info (with Firefox 68.0.2 on Debian)

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/feedbroreader/?src=search

Answer (score 3):

For Chrome, there is a handy extension from Google called [RSS Subscription Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-subscription-extensio/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd?hl=en).  It puts the standard RSS icon in the search bar if it detects the page has an RSS feed.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019, the [Feed Indicator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/feed-indicator/) extension for Firefox adds back an RSS icon in the address bar for websites that have RSS/Atom feeds.